# What kind of optimization problem is this and how can we solve it numerically?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Let $\alpha>0$, $c\in\mathbb R$, $t\in\mathbb N$ with $t\ge2$, $b_0,\ldots,b_{t-2}\ge0$ and $G_{s,\:j}\in\mathbb R$ for $s\in\{0,\ldots,t-2\}$ and $j\in\{0,\ldots,t-1\}$. Consider the function $$f(b):=\alpha\left|b_0G_{0,\:0}+\sum_{j=1}^{t-2}\frac{b_{j-1}G_{j-1,\:j}+b_jG_{j,\:j}}2+b_{t-2}G_{t-2,\:t-1}-c\right|^2+\sum_{j=1}^{t-2}\left|b_{j-1}G_{j-1,\:j}-b_jG_{j,\:j}\right|^2.$$

> Assume that we want to minimize $f$ with respect to $b$. What kind of optimization problem is this and how can we solve it numerically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to minimize a quadratic function of nonnegative variable $b\in\mathbb{R}^{t+1}$.  This is a quadratic programming (QP) problem, and you can use a QP solver.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is the function quadratic? If we define $$F:=\begin{pmatrix}G_{0,\:0}&&&&\\\displaystyle\frac{G_{0,\:1}}2&\displaystyle\frac{G_{1,\:1}}2&&&\\&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&\displaystyle\frac{G_{t-3,\:t-2}}2&\displaystyle\frac{G_{t-2,\:t-2}}2\\&&&&G_{t-2,\:t-1}\end{pmatrix},$$ then $$Fb=\begin{pmatrix}b_0G_{0,\:0}\\ b_0\displaystyle\frac{G_{0,\:1}}2+b_1\frac{G_{1,\:1}}2\\\vdots\\b_{t-3}\displaystyle\frac{G_{t-3,\:t-2}}2+b_{t-2}\frac{G_{t-2,\:t-2}}2\\b_{t-2}G_{t-2,\:t-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$ So, the first term of $f(b)$ can be written as $α\left|\langle 1,Fb\rangle-c\right|^2$.

Comment: Isn't it a least-square problem instead?

Comment: Yes, it is linear least squares with nonnegative variables. That is a special case of QP.